# How to transfer Mongo Database from one remote server to another

Tags: mongodb, compose-db, modulus.io

I need to transition several databases from one remote, cloud-based server/service (modulus.io) to another (Compose.io).  As far as I'm aware, I don't have console access on the target server, which seems to be required for using mongocopy or mongorestore.  I have all of the credentials.  How do I do this?  What command should I use, or is there a tool designed for the purpose?
I'm currently trying to use mongodump to move the database to my local machine, and then try to mongorestore it to the target machine.  This is going *very* slowly, even for a modestly sized database (<2GB) it looks like it will take most of a day to download).

Thanks

Comment: I think another option is add that new server in the replica sets of remote server. Let is synchronize and then make it primary and remove the remote server from replica set. This should work if have access to mongo admin user.

Answer (score 0):

In the Compose.io Web UI, create a new DB and click "import". There you can choose the source DB to import. Works every time! :)

I don't think this feature is available on the free tier.